# Why a function in IDA PRO has two entry points?

Tags: ida

I am using IDA pro to disassemble a large binary. I find out that in some functions, it has more than one basic block, which has no(zero) in-degree. Therefore, those basic block can be regard as one of the entry points of this function. May I know why there are more than one entry point for a particular function? And is there any way to fix the number of entry point to be one in IDA pro?

Comment: It may be a block containing some exception-handling code located within your function